# Generic constant time compare function c++

Tags: c++, templates, generics, cryptography, constant-time

I'm writing a ProtectedPtr class that protects objects in memory using Windows Crypto API, and I've run into a problem creating a generic constant time compare function. My current code:

```
template <class T>
bool operator==(volatile const ProtectedPtr& other)
{
    std::size_t thisDataSize = sizeof(*protectedData) / sizeof(T);
    std::size_t otherDataSize = sizeof(*other) / sizeof(T);

    volatile auto thisData = (byte*)getEncyptedData();
    volatile auto otherData = (byte*)other.getEncyptedData();

    if (thisDataSize != otherDataSize)
        return false;

    volatile int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < thisDataSize; i++)
        result |= thisData[i] ^ otherData[i];

    return result == 0;
}
```

getEncryptedData function:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> protectedData;
const T& getEncyptedData() const
{
    ProtectMemory(true);
    return *protectedData;
}
```

The problem is casting to byte*. When using this class with strings, my compiler complains that strings can't be casted to byte pointers. I was thinking maybe trying to base my function off of Go's ConstantTimeByteEq function, but it still brings me back to my original problem of converting a template type to an int or something that I can preform binary manipulation on.

Go's ConstantTimeByteEq function:

```
func ConstantTimeByteEq(x, y uint8) int {
    z := ^(x ^ y)
    z &= z >> 4
    z &= z >> 2
    z &= z >> 1

    return int(z)
}
```

How can I easily convert a template type into something that can have binary manipulation easily preformed on it?

**UPDATE** Working generic constant compare function based on suggestions from lockcmpxchg8b:

```
//only works on primative types, and types that don't have
//internal pointers pointing to dynamically allocated data
byte* serialize()
{
    const size_t size = sizeof(*protectedData);
    byte* out = new byte[size];

    ProtectMemory(false);
    memcpy(out, &(*protectedData), size);
    ProtectMemory(true);

    return out;
}

bool operator==(ProtectedPtr& other)
{
    if (sizeof(*protectedData) != sizeof(*other))
        return false;

    volatile auto thisData = serialize();
    volatile auto otherData = other.serialize();

    volatile int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(*protectedData); i++)
        result |= thisData[i] ^ otherData[i];

    //wipe the unencrypted copies of the data
    SecureZeroMemory(thisData, sizeof(thisData));
    SecureZeroMemory(otherData, sizeof(otherData));

    return result == 0;
}
```

Comment: Why cast it to byte and compare? Why not rely on  the compare operator of T?

Comment: `(byte*)&getEncryptedData()`?

Comment: @sajas he needs to guarantee a constant-time comparison.  He can't guarantee the default comparator won't bail out on the first difference.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b Sorry, I didn't explain that function. ProtectedPtr::getEncryptedData() returns what ProtectedPtr points to after it is encrypted in memory using CryptProtectMemory.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b edited to add the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, what you're trying to accomplish in your current code is called [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). I.e., to encrypt a `std::string` such that the resulting ciphertext is also a valid `std::string`.  This is much harder than letting the encryption process convert from the original type to a flat array of bytes.

To do the conversion to a flat array, declare a second template argument for a "Serializer" object, that knows how to serialize objects of type T into an array of unsigned char.  You could default it to a generic `sizeof`/`memcpy` serializer that would work for all primitve types.

Here's an example for `std::string`.

```
template <class T>
class Serializer
{
  public:
    virtual size_t serializedSize(const T& obj) const = 0;
    virtual size_t serialize(const T& obj, unsigned char *out, size_t max) const = 0;
    virtual void deserialize(const unsigned char *in, size_t len, T& out) const = 0;
};

class StringSerializer : public Serializer<std::string>
{
public:

  size_t serializedSize(const std::string& obj) const {
    return obj.length();
  };

  size_t serialize(const std::string& obj, unsigned char *out, size_t max) const {
    if(max >= obj.length()){
      memcpy(out, obj.c_str(), obj.length());
      return obj.length();
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("overflow");
  }

  void deserialize(const unsigned char *in, size_t len, std::string& out) const {
    out = std::string((const char *)in, (const char *)(in+len));
  }
};
```

Once you've reduced the objects down to a flat array of `unsigned char`s, then your given constant-time compare algorithm will work just fine.

Here's a really dumbed-down version of your example code using the serializer above.

```
template <class T, class S>
class Test
{
  std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> protectedData;
  size_t serSize;
public:
  Test(const T& obj) : protectedData() {
    S serializer;
    size_t size = serializer.serializedSize(obj);

    protectedData.reset(new unsigned char[size]);
    serSize = serializer.serialize(obj, protectedData.get(), size);

    // "Encrypt"
    for(size_t i=0; i< size; i++)
      protectedData.get()[i] ^= 0xa5;
  }

  size_t getEncryptedLen() const {
    return serSize;
  }
  const unsigned char *getEncryptedData() const {
    return protectedData.get();
  }

  const T getPlaintextData() const {
    S serializer;
    T target;

    //"Decrypt"
    for(size_t i=0; i< serSize; i++)
      protectedData.get()[i] ^= 0xa5;

    serializer.deserialize(protectedData.get(), serSize, target);
    return target;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string data = "test";
  Test<std::string, StringSerializer> tester(data);

  const unsigned char *ptr = tester.getEncryptedData();
  std::cout << "\"Encrypted\" bytes: ";
  for(size_t i=0; i<tester.getEncryptedLen(); i++)
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << (unsigned int)ptr[i] << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::string recov = tester.getPlaintextData();

  std::cout << "Recovered: " << recov << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
"Encrypted" bytes: d1 c0 d6 d1
Recovered: test
```

Edit: answering request for a generic serializer for primtive/flat types.  Consider this as pseudocode, because I'm typing it into a browser without testing.  I'm not sure if that's the right template syntax.

```
template<class T>
class PrimitiveSerializer : public Serializer<T>
{
public:

  size_t serializedSize(const T& obj) const {
    return sizeof obj;
  };

  size_t serialize(const T& obj, unsigned char *out, size_t max) const {
    if(max >= sizeof obj){
      memcpy(out, &obj, sizeof obj);
      return sizeof obj;
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("overflow");
  }

  void deserialize(const unsigned char *in, size_t len, T& out) const {
    if(len < sizeof out) {
      throw std::runtime_error("underflow");
    }
    memcpy(&out, in, sizeof out);
  }
};
```

Comment: So are you saying to approach the problem in this way I would need to create sterilizers for every different object I use with ProtectedPtr? Also I need to create my own FPE and not use the Windows API function I've been using?

Comment: one or the other.  You either have to use an FPE that is appropriate for your data type, or you have to be able to flatten that data down to an array of bytes.  Note that it is one serializer per *type* of object, not per object.  I almost wrote an example "generic serializer" that just takes `sizeof T`, and does `memcpy(dest_out, &obj, sizeof T)`...that would work for any object that doesn't have internal structure (i.e., internal pointers to dynamically allocated buffers).

Comment: Sorry, yeah that's what I meant, one serializer per type of object. Ok, I had actually thought before about using memcpy, but didn't know how. What would the generic serializer look like?

Comment: I added a sketch for one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your sketch worked out great, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! (pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about what error the compiler gives you.

That said, try casting to a `const char*` or `const void*`.

Another issue could be the casting from a 64-bit pointer to an 8-bit `byte`. Try casting to an `int`, `long`, or `longlong`

Edit: Based upon your feedback, another minor change:

```
volatile auto thisData = (byte*)&getEncyptedData();
volatile auto otherData = (byte*)&other.getEncyptedData();
```

(note the ampersands). That will allow the previous casts to work

Comment: This is a comment

Comment: I tried casting to all of the above, and the compiler gives errors such as 'type cast': cannot convert from 'const std::string' to '__int64'  and 'const std::string &ProtectedPtr<std::string>::getEncyptedData(void) const': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'volatile const ProtectedPtr<std::string>' to 'const ProtectedPtr<std::string> &' (those errors are specifically when trying to cast to long long)